# Get the total number of rows returned of a query using mysql

Tags: mysql

i need total number of rows returned by the query.

my query returns result like below.

[image: query returns]

What i want is only one record which is the total number of rows returned.

[image: result i want]

My query which generates the result set is :

```
 select row_number() over (order by AgentSkypeId desc) rownum, AgentSkypeId from calllogs group by AgentSkypeId;
```

Comment: data should always be posted as text not as image and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a

```
SELECT 1 rownum,COUNT(DISTINCT(AgentSkypeId )) agent FROM calllogs ;
```

I don't know why you have then rownumber in your result set